# Undecidable statement of the form “$G$ is a group”

Tags: group-theory, logic

Is there a unary predicate $\varphi(x)$ such that the formula that states "There is a set $G$ with $\forall x [x\in G\leftrightarrow\varphi(x)]$" is provable in $ZFC$ but the formula that states "$G$ is a group" is NOT decidable in $ZFC$?

**Note:** In a similar thread I asked for undecidable statements of the form "$F$ is a choice function on $M$". I am interested in more examples of undecidable statements, that is why I ask the question.

Comment: Yes, of course. But could you expand the question to include more of what inspire the question, and/or your own thoughts about it? Questions that are merely problem statements are often closed on this site; we look for questions that are more thorougly explained.

Comment: Okay, is it enough now?

Comment: Thank you; I will type up a brief answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $\psi$ be any sentence that is independent of ZFC, neither provable nor disprovable. Let $\phi(x)$ say that $x$ is an integer, and either $x$ is nonnegative or $\psi$ holds. In other words, if $\psi$ holds then $\phi$ defines the set $G = \mathbb{Z}$ and if $\psi$ does not hold then $\phi$ defines the set $G = \mathbb{N}$.

Then the claim that $(G, +_\mathbb{Z})$ is a group is independent of ZFC, although $(G, +_\mathbb{Z})$ is provably a semigroup.

Comment: Do you mean "$x$ is an integer"? And I take it that you restrict $+_{\Bbb Z}$ to $G$ implicitly?

Comment: @Lord_Farin: yes, that was a mental glitch - thanks. And yes, the operation is implicitly restricted to $G$. The main concern I have about the question is that it only asks about the set, and not about the operation, but in this case the operation cannot get more concrete.

Comment: The question made me think of [this](http://mathoverflow.net/q/12973/27117). You might already know it, but it's nice in any case.

Comment: I also thought about that, but I decided it was probably not what was being asked. But it's exactly the issue with not saying whether we want to fix $(G, \otimes)$ and ask whether it is a group, or fix $G$ and quantify over the operation $\otimes$.

Comment: In ZFC, a pair is a set. Groups are pairs (consisting of a set and of an operation on that set). So they are sets in ZFC. In my question, $G$ has to be a set that only has two elements because $G$ must be an ordered pair to be a group.

Comment: @asdfusername: my answer is consistent with that interpretation. We would let $\hat\phi(x)$ say that either $x = (0, G)$ where $G$ is as in the answer above, or $x = (1, \otimes)$ where $\otimes$ is $+_\mathbb{Z}$ restricted to $G$. Then ZFC proves that $\hat\phi$ defines a semigroup, and it is independent of ZFC whether $\hat\phi$ defines a group.